# clang-format package looking for wrong executable

Tags: package, clang

I'm trying to setup emacs to use the `clang-format` package.  I have installed the `clang-format` package from MELPA and also have `clang-format-10` (`apt install` only installs version 6 on Ubuntu) installed on my local machine.  I also have the following lines in `~/.emacs`:

```
(require 'clang-format)
(setq clang-format-style "file")
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/bin/clang-format-10")))
```

I added the last last line because `M-x clang-format-region` throws the error:

```
Searching for program: No file or directory, clang-format
```

However, the `clang-format` package appears to still be looking for a `clang-format` binary without the version suffix.  Also, it's worth noting I made an alias in my `~/.bashrc` so `clang-format` points to `clang-format-10`, however that doesn't help me in emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, .bashrc doesn’t help since it’s for non-login shell if I remember correctly.

Secondly, I believe a “path” in `exec-path` should end with “bin”, like it would be in environment variable `PATH`. Also, `/usr/bin` should already be there, thus no need to add.

What you should have done is adding a symlink. You can do:

- `sudo ln -sf clang-format-10 /usr/bin/clang-format` if you have sudo access, OR
- `ln -sf /usr/bin/clang-format-10 ~/bin/clang-format` and add `/home/yourusername/bin` to `exec-path`.